# IBM Access Client Solutions run using Java Web Start: how do I run ACS functions from the command line?

Tags: ibm-midrange, java-web-start

I have got ACS to run very nicely using Java Web Start, but I now want to use the results from the command line, e.g. to run a remote command using /plugin=rmtcmd, and cannot work out how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas please? I am assuming that I need either to work out how to find the current cached jar file (run via java -jar), or to put extra stuff in the .jnlp file (run from a URL via javaws), but there seems to be nothing anywhere on the web about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest downloading [ACS from IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1026805) and putting it in a location you know.

Comment: Hallo @David! It works fine if I do that, but I have a client who is looking at the Java Web Start option because it is potentially more easily maintainable than the local install option, while performing better than the load-from-network option.

Comment: I think the JAR is downloaded to a random name in the %USERPROFILE%/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment/cache directory.  I assume you've looked at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html for possible ways to add command line parms?

Comment: I found the random name, but I can't find anything that connects that random name back to sacsbundle.jar. I'll have a look at the Oracle link - doing it via the jnlp feels like a better route. Thanks.

Comment: Update - I can successfully pass the plugin/parameters within the .jnlp, but, because each javaws call is a completely separate instance of Java Web Start, you can't logon first and then (for example) rmtcmd, as you can with the ordinary install as @David suggested. Therefore it is clear to me that the Java Web Start option is not conducive to this sort of automation.